# UIBezierPath's close() function doesn't work for SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arkit, skshapenode

close() function should creating a line segment between the first and last points in the subpath. It works in Playground but doesn't work
when I create SKShapeNode with UIBezierPath and use it for ARSKView.
Any ideas how to fix it?

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 0))
    let shapeHeight: CGFloat = 40
    bezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: shapeHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: shapeHeight/2.0))
    bezierPath.close()

    let shape = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.cgPath, centered: true)
    shape.isAntialiased = false
    shape.strokeColor = .white
    shape.fillColor = .clear
    shape.lineWidth = 2.0
    return shape
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: SKShapeNodes have drawing issues when a line intersects on the path, which is probably why you are seeing the issue and need to attach the additional point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason why this comes , but it's very easy to fix:

```
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 0))

    bezierPath.addLine(to:  CGPoint(x: 40.0001, y: 0)) //Add this line

    let shapeHeight: CGFloat = 40
    bezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: shapeHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: shapeHeight/2.0))
    bezierPath.close()
```

Comment: So funny Apple so funny! Very strange behavior and very interesting to know why 40 doesn't work but 40.0001 works. Thanks!